# GA4 custom event only being sent in tagassistant preview mode

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I've setup a custom page_view event that triggers only under a certain condition. This means for this condition there will be two page_view events.

This works fine in preview mode in GTM and using tagassistant I can see it firing successfully with a POST payload being sent.

However, without preview mode this event does not get fired.

I've checked and the latest publish version in GTM is live and I have full admin access. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide any screenshots to show the setup of the tags?